# Orders filtering - PrestaShop API

Tags: php, api, prestashop

TL;DR 
Can't filter orders by `product_id`. When used as a parameter whole request answer is HTTP 400.

As a result I'd like to get total number of orders of a specific product. Is there any other way to achieve it?

I'm using official `PrestaShopWebservice` class, and my query looks like that:

```
      $xmlResponse = $webService->get(
        [
          'resource' => 'orders',
          'display'  => 'full',
          'output_format' => 'JSON',
          'filter[product_id]' => $id,
          'filter[valid]' => 1
        ]
      );
```

error that I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShopWebserviceException: This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means: Bad Request.
```

Thank you very much! :)